# Name of architecture with controller and that which is not MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

My current project consists of 2 projects(layers)

**1. Controller**

Inside this controller the following folders are found.

1. BusinessLogic
2. DataAccess
3. Entities

Each of these folders holds the code to connect to database, logic to connect to database and the entities contains properties.

**2. Web application**

This layer consists of the aspx pages, user controls, scripts etc

I would like to know which architecture is being followed. I am told that this is 3-tier architecture. If so, why the controller?

Comment: Is it asp.net webform (not asp.net MVC)? If yes, then MVC pattern should not applicable there since webform has different infrastructure.

Comment: Actually, are you asking why the Controller exists? The web application includes the Controllers, Views etc.. it is the encapsulation of everything that makes your web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a separation of concerns. I.e. The data access layer talks directly to the database using the entities, it has no knowledge of the business layer.  It's primary job is to connect to the database and return data.

The business layer is there to communicate with the data access layer and manipulate the data accordingly (depending on your business).

The web application then talks to your business application/domain layer and displays the contents.

Usually the data access, business layer and entities are separated via projects than folders.

Comment: Is this anyway related to WCSF? web client software factory?

Comment: Thank you. It is high time that I start learning WCSF

Answer (score 0):

First, as per your description, it seems that they just named one project as controller but it is not having any role of standard controller as per MVC pattern. They might be thinking as that project controls the business logic and data access so they just gave that name. You can ask the architect or SME (subject matter expert) of application if possible.

Second, I think you should consider the difference between Layers and Tiers. It seems you are discussing about layers here.

Layers are all about allocating the responsibilities of an application. Have a look on http://fewagainstmany.com/blog/introduction-to-layered-architecture-part-one. Three layer architecture may involves three projects or may be not.

Layers in an application are logical units of separation. For example you may have User Interface layer, Business Logic layer, Service Layer, Data Access layer. Every layer is supposed to have the code to implement that part/unit of the application.

The tier represent physical units of separation/deployment. If all layers(User Interface layer, Business Logic layer, Service Layer, Data Access layer) are deployed in same server machine, then you have just one tier. Have a look on http://blog.simcrest.com/what-is-3-tier-architecture-and-why-do-you-need-it/

Usually as the number of users (or the load on application) increases, a single server can not perform efficiently then we need to add more tiers if possible or need to user more powerful servers.

So number of tiers can be less or equal to number of layers you have. You can tell the number of layers in designing phase only, as the architecture of application is decided, but number of tiers can be confirmed after you have planned deployment.

Third, if there is just two project having some folder inside then it is just two later architecture. As explained above number of tiers depend of deployment of project.

Feel free to discuss further question if any. Thanks.